# Is it possible to get a template function to deduce the type of a template argument using either conversion or deduction guide?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction, deduction-guide

Is it possible to get the compiler to deduce the type for the template function call, using either the type conversion or the deduction guide?
And, if not, why not?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(T&& elmt)
        : m_data(std::forward<T>(elmt))
    {   }

    const T& data() const
    {
        return m_data;
    }

private:
    T m_data;
};

template<typename T>
Wrapper(T&& elmt) -> Wrapper<T>;

template<typename T>
void someFunc(const Wrapper<T>& wrapper)
{
    std::cout << wrapper.data() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    // Any chance this could work?
    // someFunc("Make me a Wrapper<const char*> please!");     //fails
    // someFunc({"Make me a Wrapper<const char*> please!"});   //fails

    // This works, but that's what I'd like to avoid
    someFunc(Wrapper{"This one works"});

    return 0;
}
```

(Compiler Explorer link: https://godbolt.org/z/eGs3raMY4)

If Wrapper wasn't a template, this would work directly:

```
#include <iostream>

class StrWrapper
{
public:
    StrWrapper(const char* str)
        : m_data(str)
    {   }

    const char* data() const { return m_data; }

private:
    const char* m_data;
};

void strFunc(const StrWrapper& wrapper)
{
    std::cout << wrapper.data() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    strFunc("This works, right?");

    return 0;
}
```

(Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/nnoaPcs91)

I know I could add an overload for each type I want the deduction for, but in this case it isn't a very practical solution (many overloads required).

Comment: I found that I can use some kind of Functor class to approach the behaviour I'd like:
https://godbolt.org/z/WsdnPGaPP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the compiler to deduce the type for the template function call, using either the type conversion or the deduction guide?

You can do a recursive approach here

```
// variable template for checking the "Wrapper<T>" type
template<typename T> inline constexpr bool is_Wrapper = false;
template<typename T> inline constexpr bool is_Wrapper<Wrapper<T>> = true;

template<typename T>
void someFunc(T&& arg)
{
    if constexpr (is_Wrapper<T>)  // if T == Wrapper<T>
        std::cout << arg.data() << std::endl;
    else  // if T != Wrapper<T>, construct explicitly and pass to the someFunc()
        someFunc(Wrapper<T>{ std::forward<T>(arg) });
}
```

This allows the both

```
someFunc("Make me a Wrapper<const char*> please!");  // works
someFunc(Wrapper{ "This one works" });               // works
```

[See a live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GMEhs77MK)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `someFunc` take a wrapper you can have it take `T` instead and then construct a wrapper inside the function like

```
template<typename T>
void someFunc(T&& to_wrap)
{
    Wrapper wrapper{std::forward<T>(to_wrap)};
    std::cout << wrapper.data() << std::endl;
}
```

Which allows

```
someFunc("Make me a Wrapper<const char*> please!");
```

to compile as seen in this [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/bW6GxsWoM).

---

The reason both

```
someFunc("Make me a Wrapper<const char*> please!");
someFunc({"Make me a Wrapper<const char*> please!"});
```

fail is that they are not `Wrapper`'s, and the compiler will not try to convert the arguments, so there is no way for the compiler to deduce what `T` should be.

Comment: I think that's what I don't understand: why doesn't the compiler try to convert? It would if it wasn't a template function, I guess.
Is it that template deduction happens first and fails, so there is no candidate function to try the conversion?

Comment: @Michel Yes.  Template deduction doesn't do conversions because there is essentially an infinite number of types the parameter could be converted into.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense :)
It makes me wonder if we should have deduction guides for function templates: it works for a constructor if a deduction guide is provided, and a constructor is a kind of function~ Would be nice to have a generalization of that.

Comment: @Michel We pretty much already have that, it's called overloading.  You can leverage overloading like `void someFunc(const char* str) { someFunc(Wrapper{str}); }`